# How can I view or start Java Web Start Applications?

Tags: java

Where can I find a menu or launchers for Javaws apps that I have installed?

I am using OpenJDK x86.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<del>Yep, the finally implemented the option `-viewer` which enables us to see the cached/installed Java Web Start applications.</del>

They changed this, now this is embedded in the JDK Control Panel which can be launched in unity or in cli using `itweb-settings`. Go to the cache sidemenu and click on view files.
[image]

Comment: You know if this is still valid? I run "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/javaws -viewer" but it open a windows to see installed certificates not applications.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I updated the post with other  workaround that I found.

Answer (score 17):

Using the Iced Tea

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-netx
```

Then type

```
javaws /path/to/your.jnlp
```

Comment: Or simply double click

Comment: Says it can't read my jnlp file.

Answer (score 14):

Just use javaws as you normally would.

```
javaws /path/to/your.jnlp
```

If you want to open in nautilus:

right click on your file -> Open with other application... -> Use custom command -> `/usr/bin/javaws`

Answer (score 3):

if you are using sunjava, select Applications on your Desktop (upper left). Choose internet from menu. Select Sunjava Webstart. Your installed applications should popup.

Comment: It's right, but I was wondering how could I do that with OpenJDK.

Comment: 2019, for Oracle Java, under Internet menu, Oracle Java 8 Web Start.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately,
  sudo apt-get install icedtea-net
will not work with Oracle JRE 13 or newer.
See https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/IcedTea-Web/issues/437
bug fixed in 2.0, icedtea is 1.8 in even the newest Ubuntu releases.

Answer (score 0):

I went to this website (https://www.labsrc.com/running-cisco-asdm-under-linux/) and followed the instructions listed below.

Go to https://java.com/en/download/

Click on the Linux x64 download link and save it to your Downloads folder.

```
mkdir ~/java

tar -xvf ~/Download/jre-8u301-linux-x64.tar.gz -C ~/java

~/java/jre1.8.0_301/bin/javaws https://192.168.1.1/admin/public/asdm.jnlp
```